# Nested Enum type in C++ or C#?

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures, enum

I've come across a recurring issue in a few of my recent projects in which I find myself using enums to represent state, or type, or something else, and I need to check against a few conditions. Some of these conditions span multiple enums, so I end up with a load of logic in `switch` and `if` blocks, which I don't like. This is a particular problem when having to cast things to and from the enum, like when the enum is being used to check an int that you're getting from a web request or a calculation.

Is there something in C++ or C# that can be used as a nested enum? Something like this:

```
enum Animal
{
    Mammal
    {
        Cat,
        Dog,
        Bear
    },
    Bird
    {
        Pigeon,
        Hawk,
        Ostrich
    },
    Fish
    {
        Goldfish,
        Trout,
        Shark
    },
    Platypus    //srsly what is that thing
};
```

Obviously, it may or may not be declared like that, but you get the idea. The point is that in code you could use it like `Animal thisAnimal = Animal.Mammal.Cat` and then later check `if (thisAnimal.IsMember(Animal.Mammal))` or something like that.

I've seen Java's EnumSet, and found them pretty useful, but I don't think they're an exact match for the functionality I'm after. For this example, you'd have to declare an enum with all the animals at one level, and then add them all to the relevant sets. That would mean that when using the original enum, higher-level things like `Mammal` or `Invertebrate` would appear on the same "level" as something very specific like `African Swallow`, which would imply that they were (to some degree) interchangeable, which isn't true. In theory, a nested structure as above might allow you to specify the level of "specificness" needed, so you could get this:

```
enum Animal::Kingdom.Order.Family.Genus.Species
{ /*stuff*/ }

Organism::Kingdom.Phylum.Class.Order.Family thisThing;

thisThing = Animalia.Cordata;                               //compiler error
thisThing = Animalia.Chordata.Aves.Passeri.Hirundinidae;    //compiles OK
```

Does a structure like this exist anywhere? If not, how might I build one for C++ and/or C# and have it remain as generic and re-usable as possible?

Comment: This is why OOP exists. Enums are supposed to be simple listings. If any complex hiearchy is required, you should create your own structures.

Comment: @Euphoric Generally I'd agree, but when all you want to do is list simple data like "is this a thing" and "what sort of thing is it" it seems like overkill to build a whole set of classes. The situations where I'd use this are cases where an enum is almost good enough, but too flat. I used the example of animals - if the software was doing something with animals, I'd use something more complex, but for, say, landlord's management software, all you need is what type of pet the tenant has so you can check `if (Tenant.Pet.IsMember(Animal::Fish))` because they're only allowed a fish, or something.

Comment: KISS. There is no need for ANY hiearchy for landlord's management. Just have single enum as type of animal. You should always do minimum effort required to satisfy the functional requirements. Anything more is useless over-engineering.

Comment: Ok, bad example perhaps, but there are definitely cases where you might have an enum, and you have a case where only a subset of the enum values are valid for a thing. A better example might be a game in which an enum maps to action types and you wish to check whether the player is making a movement, interaction or combat action at a given point. Each of those sets contain several enum values, but they need to all be part of the ActionType enum so that you can pass them to the method that handles them.

Comment: @anaximander: The problem is that enums call for switch statements to handle them. And switch statements are a nightmare when you need to extend the enum. If your enum is large enough that it needs subcategories, it is certainly large enough to expand regularly. Here is the advantage of OOP: You can define all necessary operations (such as isMovement(), isInteraction(), isCombat()) and your application scales completely differently when you add new actions.

Comment: @anaximander But you probably don't want to use enums for that, a class hierarchy would be better. For example movement needs coordinates, but combat action needs target and you don't do that well with enums.

Comment: As a note, the example you've used is simply namespace. `namespace Animal { enum Mammal { cat, dog ... `

Comment: @thiton Oddly enough, I'm hoping to use this to *avoid* switch statements; I'm aiming to use this as the key in a Dictionary where the values are function pointers. A class hierachy is less attractive because the initial value is coming from a web request, so to create them I'd need a (potentially large) factory implementation; it'd be nicer to just cast this value to an enum and throw an error if it doesn't match.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Namespaces would only let me assign the bottom level, and wouldn't let me easily check if a certain thing is in one "namespace" or another. I wouldn't be able to declare `Animal thisAnimal;` because `Animal` is a namespace, not a type.

Comment: @anaximander How is a dictionary of enums and a factory method to create the enum from a string better than actual class hierarchy and factory method to get instance of the right class using a dictionary?

Comment: A platypus is a monotreme, which is a kind of egg-laying mammal. It's in a small group of other animals along with echidnas. *The more you know*

Comment: As I feared, I don't think there's a way of doing it. It doesn't help that every time I think of a place you could use it, someone provides a different (and often perfectly valid) way of doing it. I think I'll give up on the search for nested enums for now. I still think it's a potentially useful language feature though.

Comment: @KChaloux, and monotremes are mammals, so the code can include Platypus after Bear just fine.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with others that this seems overengineered. Usually, you want either a simple enum or a complex hierarchy of classes, it's not a good idea to combine the two.

But if you really want to do this (in C#), I think it's useful to recap what exactly do you want:

- Separate types for the hierarchy `Kingdom`, `Phylum`, etc., which *do not* form inheritance hierarchy (otherwise, `Phylum` could be assigned to `Kingdom`). Though they could inherit from a common base class.
- Each expression like `Animalia.Chordata.Aves` has to be assignable to a variable, which means we have to work with instances, not nested static types. This is especially problematic for the root type, because there are no global variables in C#. You could solve that by using a singleton. Also, I think there should be only one root, so the code above would become something like `Organisms.Instance.Animalia.Chordata.Aves`.
- Each member has to be a different type, so that `Animalia.Chordata` compiled, but `Plantae.Chordata` didn't.
- Each member needs to somehow know all its children, for the `IsMember()` method to work.

The way I would implement these requirements is to start with a class like `EnumSet<TChild>` (though the name could be better), where `TChild` is the type of the children of this level in hierarchy. This class would also contain a collection of all its children (see later about filling it). We also need another type to represent leaf level of the hierarchy: non-generic `EnumSet`:

```
abstract class EnumSet
{}

abstract class EnumSet<TChild> : EnumSet where TChild : EnumSet
{
    protected IEnumerable<TChild> Children { get; private set; }

    public bool Contains(TChild child)
    {
        return Children.Contains(child);
    }
}
```

Now we need to create a class for each level in the hierarchy:

```
abstract class Root : EnumSet<Kingdom>
{}

abstract class Kingdom : EnumSet<Phylum>
{}

abstract class Phylum : EnumSet
{}
```

And finally some concrete classes:

```
class Organisms : Root
{
    public static readonly Organisms Instance = new Organisms();

    private Organisms()
    {}

    public readonly Animalia Animalia = new Animalia();
    public readonly Plantae Plantae = new Plantae();
}

class Plantae : Kingdom
{
    public readonly Anthophyta Anthophyta = new Anthophyta();
}

class Anthophyta : Phylum
{}

class Animalia : Kingdom
{
    public readonly Chordata Chordata = new Chordata();
}

class Chordata : Phylum
{}
```

Notice that children are always fields of the parent class. What this means is that to fill the `Children` collection, we can use reflection:

```
public EnumSet()
{
    Children = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .Select(f => f.GetValue(this))
                        .Cast<TChild>()
                        .ToArray();
}
```

One problem with this approach is that `Contains()` always works only one level down. So, you can do `Organisms.Instance.Contains(animalia)`, but not `.Contains(chordata)`. You can do that by adding overloads of `Contains()` to the specific hierarchy classes, e.g.:

```
abstract class Root : EnumSet<Kingdom>
{
    public bool Contains(Phylum phylum)
    {
        return Children.Any(c => c.Contains(phylum));
    }
}
```

But this would be a lot of work for deep hierarchies.

---

After all of this, you end up with quite a lot of repetitive code. One way to fix that would be to have a text file that describes the hierarchy and use a T4 template to generate all the classes based on that.

Comment: Yeah... that's a lot of code. And it's still not generic; it's tied to classification of organisms - you couldn't reuse it for, say, state, or player actions in a game, or days of the week, or something. Not criticising; just looks like it can't be done.

Comment: Well, it would be generic if you did it using code generation. Otherwise, I don't think you can make something like this generic.

Comment: Code generation isn't really something I fancy getting into, for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way you can implement it: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/24969525/538387

But as you see, it adds more complexity to the code, which is not a good practice in general.

I suggest to keep every enum values flat, just like a normal enum definition, and add a few extension or helper methods. like:

```
public enum Animal
{
    // Mammals
    Cat,
    Dog,
    Bear

    // Birds
    Pigeon,
    Hawk,
    Ostrich

    // Fishes
    Goldfish,
    Trout,
    Shark
};


public static class AnimalExtension
{
    public static bool IsMammal(this Animal animal)
    {
        return animal == Animal.Cat
            || animal == Animal.Dog
            || animal == Animal.Bear;
    }

    public static bool IsBird(this Animal animal)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static bool IsFish(this Animal animal)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So you can easily write in your code:

```
Animal animal = GetValueFromASource();

if (animal.IsMammal())
{
    Console.Write("This is a mammal.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to use bit flags. If you are not familiar see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/system.flagsattribute.aspx). The general idea is simple yet still falls in line with your need to use enums.

Each grouping of, for lack of a better work, classes, is just a span of bits. So for mammals you just delegate a stretch of bits. In your case you would have your None(0x0) organism, perhaps the Platypus. Then 0x1 is Cat, 0x2 is dog, 0x4 is bear. To check for inclusion in the Mammals category just AND it with a 7 and be sure the result is the value being checked.

To check for inclusion in the Animal kingdom you would just AND it with the all bit flagged stretch of values you have.

This is not exactly the best technique for scalability but it may be the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Broadly agree, although I'd use a bit field for animal or other things at this level, then a bit field which decided between bird/mammal/fish, then a bit field choosing between fish, or choosing between mammals, etc. And reserve a few values for categories you haven't thought of...

Answer (score 0):

Enums are integral types and that is not going to change so whatever solution we come up with we can stop calling it an enum.

All speculation about bad design decisions aside, I suggest you use a string with a reserved separator character. The purpose is still identification, you just do not like the flatness.

So how about Animal_Mammal_Cat for an id?

You can easily split that into its subparts and process it using a nested switch statement. That will give you the opportunity to invoke custom handling based on the "class" of identifier you are dealing with.

It is not that uncommon in business administration to have identifiers that have contextual information in them. Like order number 202004201 as the first order on April 20th of 2020. Guaranteed to be unique, can be used a technical id (key) and provides a way to filter in time.

Comment: Eh, no. However common you think it is doesn't make it any less wrong. Parsing strings for data is a primitive attempt at data management. If you need multiple fields from <something> then you should just create a class with those fields explicitly defined and separate from each other. There's no (reasonable) justification not to.

Comment: @searchengine27 It is not wrong, it is addressing a need. Like offering an efficient way to enter data, create a new id or conveying information instantly to the user reading the field. If you want to manipulate or process data automatically you can still have that class that you talk about but that would address a different purpose.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is there are much better approaches to the two things you just suggested as reasons to do this. Entering data is complicated by the need to concatenate data unnecessarily. IDs should NEVER be concatenated data, and should be made of composite keys. Manipulating data is thereby easier as well. Whether or not you will modify is irrelevant - the data is always accessed separately. Why complicate all that just because? There's no strong reason to ever concatenate data into a single string. In fact, there's usually plenty of evidence to the contrary where you should never do it.